# Check if an array or objects has a specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to check if an object in an array has a key before performing a map.

My initial object array looks like:

```
[{label: "", value: ""}, {label: "", value: ""}]
```

I have a method which changes the above array so that I can post it back. This then looks like:

```
["STRING","STRING"]
```

The method I'm trying is:

```
var returiningUsers = [];
if (this.state.users.length > 0) {
  returiningUsers = this.state.users.map(user => user.value)
  console.log('has users with value');
}
return returiningUsers
```

The above works if there are 2 or more items in the array. When the array structure changes I get the following error: `TypeError: _this.state.users.map is not a function`.

I need to check if the object array key exists before doing the map function. Is this possible?

Comment: if your array changes to ['string','some other string'] the key is just 0,1,2 right ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  I need to check if the object array has a key of "value". Then perform the mapping else do nothing.

Comment: This has naught to do with ReactJS.

Comment: The object array is within `this.state` so I believe it does!

Comment: "I need to check if the object array key exists before doing the map function." -- I think you are approaching this from the wrong end. You should structure your code so that this isn't a question you're trying to answer right before doing an array map. This could be as simple as storing 2 different arrays (that represent 2 different structures) or just never storing the derived structure (the result of the mapped array) since you can always derive it from the source structure. The error `map is not a function` sounds like an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has an object property for this

```
myObj.hasOwnProperty('key')
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "changes the structure" but you can also just filter the array for objects that have the key you are looking for

```
if (this.state.users.length > 0) {
  returiningUsers = this.state.users.filter(user => user.hasOwnProperty('value'))
}
```

Comment: Please explain what error you got and what you were expecting to happen.

Comment: It doesn't find the value even though the value exists prior to method call. I've updated the question for greater clarity.

Comment: I don't see the update. I also showed how to filter the array. Perhaps this is what you want to do if you just want all the objects in an array that contain a certain field. If not, can you please explain what the final output is that you would like in this example.

Comment: I'm glad you could come out with an answer. It's pretty hard to understand what the problem is.

Comment: I have an array of objects which after "X" function happens changes the array of objects to just a simple array of strings. Then the above method "Z"  tries to map user.value but user.value doesn't exist at this point and throws the error. How can I check if the object array has a key of "value" . Simple enough?

Comment: That is a bit complicated to understand. What do you mean by "changes the array of objects to just a simple array of strings". You seem to be creating a new array with values of the 'value' key in each object. Do you want to know if all the objects contain the "value" key before you do the map?

Comment: I have a state.users which is [{user: "", value: ""},{user: "", value: ""},{user: "", value: ""}] which then changes to ["","",""] (note the missing of {} and the missing of user and value keys?

Comment: The map function does not change arrays, it is an immutable method which means it creates an entirely new array. `returiningUsers` is new, `this.state.users` remains intact. Please help us understand what the final outcome is that you would like and I can help.

Comment: Forgive the frustration on this, but google search links are all purple in this. I just want to check if the `this.state.users` has a key called "value" . I've tried `hasOwnProperty('value')` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us your code. It should work, that is what it is designed to do. Maybe you are implementing it wrong. Please add the code where you use it to the question along with the error you get.

Comment: I guess, roughly guess, in your scenario, you want to check element of stats.users is still a object or being changed to primitive string? So you should just check typeof element instead of checking if it still has a key?